# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

Tags: jquery

I'm summarizing my key problem here.

I've the different links on which I want to check if the user moves the mouse outside the list or not.

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    //do something here
},function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
            if($('li').is(':hover') === false )
            console.log('out');
        },100);
});
```

Where, `if($('li').is(':hover') === false )` is to check if the hover is there or not in all lists.

Suppose, if you hover on `bar` and hover on `foo` then it should not log the text `out` but if you hover on `bar` and move mouse outside any list i.e. `foo` in my example then it should log `out`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92sq1nd7/)

Comment: That error message looks like $('li') returns empty list. Did you have any 'li' elements in your DOM?

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle in my question?

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't spot it earlier... So, I've looked there and I don't know what's the cause of the error. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting that error but you could use this if statement instead to check for hover.

```
if ($('li:hover').length === 0)
```

Comment: jQuery's selector engine Sizzle does not seem to support pseudo selector `:hover` and will raise above mentioned error "unsupported pseudo".